# WPF: disable ListViewItem base on model view property

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

So I have this `ModelView` property that changed when my application do my stuff:

```
private bool isPlay;
public bool IsPlay
{
    get { return isPlay; }
    set
    {
        isPlay = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsPlay");
    }
}
```

And when this `IsPlay` is `True` I want my `ListViewItem` `IsEnabled = False` so this is my `Style` my `ListView` using:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
        <!-- ListViewItem -->
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />-->
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                    <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                          Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>

                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsPlay}" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.1"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The problem is that the `ListViewItem` `IsEnabled` not changed so I bind this `IsPlay` property into some `TextBlock` to see is its change its state properly (`True` to `False` or vice versa) and this working fine but my `ListView` `Style` not.

**Update**

Here the declaration of my `View Model` (only one instance):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:ViewModelBase/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Is the `IsPlay` property a property of each item viewmodel within the list?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I have the `IsPlay` property within the item viewmodel, it is triggering the disable as expected.

Comment: Have you tried using `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsPlay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}"`with defining BooleanInverterConverter as just doing `!` on the boolean it recieves?

Comment: user @grek40 IsPlay  is property in my view model and as i mentioned i try to bind it to TextBlock and the property works it just not in my ListViewItem, and user@ i haven't try yet Converter

Comment: Maybe i need to declare this as static ?

Comment: Please describe in Details what viewmodel instances you have, where they are bound etc. Having a single viewmodel with a list of items sounds wrong.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListViewItem.DataContext` is bound to the data items of your list, so you can't directly access properties that exist at the level of the `ListView`.

You can use a relative binding in this case:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsPlay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView,Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True"/>
```